# CXF: method gets called twice - interceptor exception

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, cxf

I have written a webservice with Apache CXF to bundle access to a DB2 database. This service gets called by another webservice and sometimes it happens that these calls are processed twice. The result is that some entries in my tables are doubled which causes further problems. Everytime this happens a `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault` exception is thrown and i have no idea why. According to the log file the two processes happen within 1-2 ms so i assume this might be a problem with threading but i do not fully understand the stacktrace. Any help is appreciated.

This webservice is running on Java7 in a Jetty 7.2.2.

Full stracktrace below:
(Sorry for german parts in there. "starte speichern" means "start saving" and "erfolgreich gespeichert" means "succesfully saved")

```
08:09:49.166 [jetty-36] INFO  d.v.g.w.v.s.i.VorgangsdatenServiceImpl - Starte Speichern des Vorgangs mit der VorgangsID E2016-06-24-08.09.48.993000/1 
08:09:49.167 [jetty-31] INFO  d.v.g.w.v.s.i.VorgangsdatenServiceImpl - Starte Speichern des Vorgangs mit der VorgangsID E2016-06-24-08.09.48.993000/1 
08:09:49.176 [jetty-36] INFO  d.v.g.w.v.s.i.VorgangsdatenServiceImpl - SET_VORGANG INSERT INTO DMS.VORGANGSPOOL_PUFFER : Vorgang 'E2016-06-24-08.09.48.993000 / 1' erfolgreich gespeichert. 
08:09:49.177 [jetty-36] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://xxx}Service#{http://xxx}setVorgang has thrown exception, unwinding now 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:108) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:534) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1351) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:77) [jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:170) [jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:516) [jetty-security-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:929) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:864) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:121) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1068) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805) [jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) [jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:508) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:451) [jetty-util-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: c: null
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:255) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:106) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:149) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:96) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:253) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
08:09:49.178 [jetty-31] INFO  d.v.g.w.v.s.i.VorgangsdatenServiceImpl - SET_VORGANG INSERT INTO DMS.VORGANGSPOOL_PUFFER : Vorgang 'E2016-06-24-08.09.48.993000 / 1' erfolgreich gespeichert. 
08:09:49.180 [jetty-36] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://xxx}Service#{xxx}setVorgang has thrown exception, unwinding now 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:366) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:534) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1351) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:77) [jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:170) [jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:516) [jetty-security-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:929) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403) [jetty-servlet-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:864) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:151) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:121) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1068) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805) [jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218) [jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:508) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:451) [jetty-util-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:911) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.complete(HttpGenerator.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.commitResponse(HttpConnection.java:721) [jetty-server-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Output.close(HttpConnection.java:1125) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$WrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:799) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$BackChannelConduit.close(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:729) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-core-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:187) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:275) [jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar:7.2.2.v20101205]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:849) ~[na:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you discarded two client requests?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://everflux.de/jetty-org-eclipse-jetty-io-eofexception-connection-closed-1788/). Seems to be a jetty timeout problem. Regarding your doubled entries I would have a look at your software-architecture to ensure that your websevice is atomic. But that's another story and should perhaps asked in another question with more information (code and so on).

Comment: According to the log files of the calling webservice it does only make one request but i agree, since jetty is working in two threads there have to be two requests. We are suspecting that CXF sends a request and thinks by mistake an error occured and sends a second right away. That would explain why the first started thread couldn't finish properly. The Problem is, at the time i see the error my business logic is already finished.

Comment: You can add a LoggingInterceptor in client and in server  to see if request is duplicated or is a jetty problem

Comment: I think adding an interceptor is a good idea but i had no time yet. Interesting is that we are getting the same errors in another webservice if it is under high load. My own webservice is usually also under high load. Maybe this could be hint.

Comment: I added an interceptor for logging but the problem didn't occur since then, so i build a new .war without logging and the problem still seems to be gone. That's nice of course but it bothers me to not know what happened here. All .war are build by the same jenkins so there should be no differences. It's also strange that it only happened in one of a few hundred calls.